# How do web browser games access temporary files

Tags: flash, web-applications

There is a web game that I play and I used fiddler to see what temporary files it downloaded. While I was playing I deleted all those temporary files including the sounds and flash files. But it didn't affect the game at all. Why is that? I checked in fiddler and it doesn't look like the files were redownloaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably, you browser loaded the files into memory and also cached them to disk, so deleting the cached copies doesn't keep it from continuing to execute the files in memory. If you leave the page and go back again, however, your browser will need to download the files again if they have been removed from the disk cache (unless by chance it keeps files cached in memory as well, YMMV).